# Navigation Component - How to Nest Navigation Graph?

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components

I am looking for example with Navigation Component in Android that will use multiple navigation graphs and then show how to nest them together? 
Could you give any example or hint? It is new feature in Android, and there are only simple Single Activity examples with NavHostFragment, but how to use multiple navigation graphs correctly nest them or switch from one nav graph to another. What are the best practices?